# how to determine which checkbox is cheked in customized listview using arrayadapter?

Tags: android, listview

i have an customized list view but if i use the check box then list item is not clickable & also focusable. actually i want to find the checked items from list view & delete the checked items from list view.

Answer (score 0):

set the listeneres like onClick or onFocus on the instance of View you are getting in your getView() of custom adapter. It will work.